# Can't install pandas 1.0.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip

I previously installed **Python 3.10** but I get an error when installing **pandas**. I also tried installing numpy

```
python3 -m pip install pandas==1.0.1
```

The error message is:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-168o70t9\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ro_5wn6d\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.13' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (578 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-63.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
  Collecting wheel
    Downloading wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting Cython>=0.29.13
    Downloading Cython-0.29.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (985 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.14.5
    Downloading numpy-1.14.5.zip (4.9 MB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
    Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rafin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dauru1fc\\numpy_b14b965ac6cf4bcbb8f4baaab5f641e5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rafin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dauru1fc\\numpy_b14b965ac6cf4bcbb8f4baaab5f641e5\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-vq0mqgb6'
         cwd: C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dauru1fc\numpy_b14b965ac6cf4bcbb8f4baaab5f641e5\
    Complete output (264 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
    C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dauru1fc\numpy_b14b965ac6cf4bcbb8f4baaab5f641e5\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py:464: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
      return is_string(s) and ('*' in s or '?' is s)
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dauru1fc\numpy_b14b965ac6cf4bcbb8f4baaab5f641e5\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dauru1fc\numpy_b14b965ac6cf4bcbb8f4baaab5f641e5\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dauru1fc\numpy_b14b965ac6cf4bcbb8f4baaab5f641e5\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\libs
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\libs
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\libs
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\libs
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\rafin\\miniconda3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dauru1fc\numpy_b14b965ac6cf4bcbb8f4baaab5f641e5\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dauru1fc\numpy_b14b965ac6cf4bcbb8f4baaab5f641e5\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
    Running setup.py clean for numpy
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rafin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dauru1fc\\numpy_b14b965ac6cf4bcbb8f4baaab5f641e5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rafin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dauru1fc\\numpy_b14b965ac6cf4bcbb8f4baaab5f641e5\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
         cwd: C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dauru1fc\numpy_b14b965ac6cf4bcbb8f4baaab5f641e5
    Complete output (10 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.

    `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

      - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
      - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                          files that aren't checked into the git repo)

    Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).

    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
  Failed to build numpy
  Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, numpy, Cython
      Running setup.py install for numpy: started
      Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, 
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rafin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dauru1fc\\numpy_b14b965ac6cf4bcbb8f4baaab5f641e5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rafin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dauru1fc\\numpy_b14b965ac6cf4bcbb8f4baaab5f641e5\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kcpsi8lm\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ro_5wn6d\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ro_5wn6d\overlay\Include\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/c3/e8c56de02d6c52f8541feca2fd77117e8ae4956f7b3e5cdbed726624039b/pandas-1.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=3c07765308f091d81b6735d4f2242bb43c332cc3461cae60543df6b10967fe27 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/) (requires-python:>=3.6.1). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\rafin\miniconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-168o70t9\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\rafin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ro_5wn6d\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.13' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==1.0.1 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.22.0, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.23.3, 0.23.4, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2, 0.25.0, 0.25.1, 0.25.2, 0.25.3, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.0.1
```

I then tried to uninstall 3.10 and installed the lower version, 3.9, but still got the same error. I am new to python. Should I reinstall lower versions of python up to 3.6? However, I also need miniconda3 (which uses python 3.9). Will this affect my conda version? Any advice?

Comment: How about running `pip install pandas`? Is there a need for it to be version `1.0.1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't install `Pandas==1.0.1` with `Python>=3.9`:

https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.0.1/#files

You need a Python version between 3.6 and 3.8.

**Update**

Try:

```
conda create -n py38 python=3.8.13 pandas=1.0.1
conda activate py38
conda list

# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
...
pandas                    1.0.1            py38h0573a6f_0  
...
python                    3.8.13               h12debd9_0  
...
```

Comment: I now installed python 3.7.9 but i still get the same error

Comment: Don't use `pip`, use `conda` to create a virtual env then install right versions. Check my update